# phpmyadmin "no data received to import" error, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using XAMPP on a pc atwork to host a database.  I exported a backup ("bintra.sql") using [phpmybackuppro](http://www.phpmybackuppro.net/).  I use xampp on a mac at home, and when I try to import the sql file located on my desktop, I get this error.

```
No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.
```

Now, the file size of bintra.sql is 922kb. The max size allowed indicated on the phpmyadmin screen is 3,072KiB, so I don't think it is the size that is preventing the import.

I'm using phpmyadmin v2.11.7

Does anyone have any ideas why no data is being received to import?

**Comment Responses:**

These are my upload settings from php.ini

```
;Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On
;Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not specified). 
//upload_tmp_dir =
;Maximum allowed size for uploaded
files. 

upload_max_filesize = 3M
;Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M
```

**EDIT:**

Tried using Mamp instead.  Works fine with the same sql file.  I don't know why.

Comment: what are your php.ini values for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size?

Comment: Philippe, I added that info into the question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows. Turns out it was caused by the temporary directory PHP uses for uploads. By default this is C:\Windows\Temp, which is not writable for PHP.

In php.ini, add:

```
upload_tmp_dir = C:\inetpub\temp
```

Make sure to remove any other `upload_tmp_dir` settings. Set permissions on `C:\inetpub\temp` so `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS` have write permission. Restart the web server and you should be fine.

Comment: Nice to see an answer to the problem instead of a workaround.  Thanks.

Answer (score 111):

I HAD THE SAME PROBLEM AND THIS WORKED FOR ME :

```
Try these different settings in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\bin\php.ini

Find:
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M

Change to:
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Then restart your xampp or wamp to take effect

or stop then start only apache in xammp

Comment: thanks it worked!! and at the top of the file add **ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);** if you get Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: Old but gold. Thanks, Mohammad.

Comment: Worked exactly! Thanks, that should be the correct answer.

Comment: After these changes if you use nginx and php-fpm, you can execute the following commands: `/etc/init.d/php-fpm` restart and `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: If you'd rather leave your php.ini as is and you are using PHP via a CGI/FCGI SAPI, then you can simply paste the revised settings into a .user.ini file in phpMyAdmin's root directory and restart your server. They will then apply only to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 13):

Check permissions for you upload directory. You can find its path inside `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` file.

In my case (Ubuntu 14.04) it was:

```
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

So I checked permissions for `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp` and it turns out that the directory wasn't writable for my Apache user (which is by default `www-data`). It could be the case especially if you changed your apache user like I do.

Comment: same problem from my side, on /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp right, Thanks

Comment: Fixed it for me on a dev machine I'd overwritten the default apache user for

Answer (score 9):

Open your php.ini file use CNTRL+F to search for the following settings which may be the culprit:

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- memory_limit
- max_input_time
- max_execution_time

Make sure to save a copy of the php.ini prior to making changes. You will want to adjust the settings to accommodate your file size, and increase input and/or execution time.

Remember to restart your services after making changes.

**Warning!** There may be some unforeseen drawbacks if you adjust these settings too liberally. I am not expert enough to know this for sure.

Source: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,20757,20935

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using XAMPP. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

```
xampp in ubuntu

cd /opt/lampp/etc
vim php.ini

Find:
  post_max_size = 8M
  upload_max_filesize = 2M
  max_execution_time = 30
  max_input_time = 60
  memory_limit = 8M

Change to:
  post_max_size = 750M
  upload_max_filesize = 750M
  max_execution_time = 5000
  max_input_time = 5000
  memory_limit = 1000M

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 6):

It’s a common error and it can be easily fixed. This error message is an indication of that the file you are trying to import is larger than your web host allows

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
>   the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
>   configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

**Solution:**

A solution is easy, Need to increase file size upload limit **as per your requirement.**

First of all, **stop** the **XAMPP/Wamp** and then find the `php.ini` in the following locations. Windows: **C:\xampp\php\php.ini**

Open the `php.ini` file. Find these lines in the `php.ini` file and replace it following numbers

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

And then **restart** your **XAMPP/Wamp**

---

**NOTE:** For Windows, you can find the file in the ***C:\xampp\php\php.ini***-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder)

Comment: yes that is the solution increasing filesize upload

Answer (score 4):

Kind of cheating I guess...but you can also zip the sql file and then import it. I've had that issue in the past when I was working with forum software and was always a simple fix.

Comment: Wow, I forgot about the zip. Ty.

Comment: This hack worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **xampp** you can find `php.ini` file by going into **xampp** **control panel** and and clicking `config` button in front of Apache.

Answer (score 2):

if in any case you haven't found a fix that you needed that were written above, a simple fix is to zip your .sql file and import the zipped file on phpMyAdmin.

This should work as long as the zip file size would not be more than the maximum upload bytes in your phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

I never succeeded importing dumb files using phpmyadmin or phpMyBackupPro
better is to go to console or command line ( whatever it's called in mac ) and do the following:

mysql -u username -p databasename

replace username with the username you use to connect to mysql, then it will ask you to enter the password for that username, and that's it

you can import any size of dumb using this method

Answer (score 1):

**No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.**

These are my upload settings from php.ini

```
upload_tmp_dir = "D:\xampp\xampp\tmp"       ;//set these for temp file storing

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 10M    ;//change it according to max file upload size
```

I am sure your problem will be short out using this instructions.

```
 upload_tmp_dir = "D:\xampp\xampp\tmp"
```

Here you can set any directory that can hold temp file, I have installed in D: drive xampp so I set it  "D:\xampp\xampp\tmp".

Answer (score 1):

Change your upload settings in php.ini configuration file

Change the below settings to these values:

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Answer (score 0):

just copy your source DataBase(from your PC C:\xampp\mysql\data\"your data base"), then copy it to the destination folder in your MAC (/Application/Xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql).

don't forget to set the permission of the new copied folder(your DataBase) in your MAC otherwise you can't see your tables!

to set the permission:
 -go to the folder of your DataBase(/Application/Xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/"your data base")
 -right click on it
 -select Get info
 -in the sharing&permissions you must add your user account(i.e. administrator or everyone)
 -choose its privilege to Read & Write
 -choose Apply to enclosed items

enjoy your Database ;)

Answer (score 0):

*if none of the above solutions worked for you.*

in my case phpmyadmin was using a deferent configuration file(php.ini). to know what config file used by phpmyadmin :

go `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` then edit `index.php` file and make it start with this

```
<?php
phpinfo();
die();
// ...
```

now when you visit `localhost/phpmyadmin` you can search for `php.ini`.

you can tell where the config file is , in my case it was `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini`

now you need to update `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` and you may need to change `upload_tmp_dir`

save your changes and then run `sudo service apache2 restart`

now everything should be OK

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these answer but none succeed. even with heidisql
Then I open my.ini files
it turned out this line

```
performance_schema = off
```

So I turned it on, performance_schema = on,
the importing with heidisql works, but phpmyadmin still not woking

Finally I update phpmyadmin to the latest version (ver 5.2 at this time), and it works, importing works again