# Changing the max_upload_filesize in php.ini but it stays the same in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am dealing with the following problem, as i described at the title, I am changing the `max_upload_filesize` in `php.ini` in order to upload my database but the settings in `phpMyAdmin` stays the same.. Any ideas why this is happening??
I have this problem a month and i have to find a solution.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you change the right `php.ini`? If so, I think you need to restart apache to see changes, don't you?

Comment: I have changed the php.in in the following path /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and gave for both upload_max_filesize and max_post_size the value of 50.

Comment: use phpinfo() ,check which ini file is loaded

Comment: i did that too. The ini file that loaded is in the path /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. That php.ini changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try these different settings in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\bin\php.ini

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

And Restart your server

Comment: Did that but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

When you change `upload_max_filesize` value you should also change `post_max_size` value.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 15M

; Maximum size for a POST REQUEST (This value MUST be greater than
; upload_max_filesize)
post_max_size = 30M
```

Also `memory_limit` value must be grater than `post_max_size`.

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: As i said in my comment i did that. But i'll try it once more, i don't have something to lose.

Comment: I tried it and nothing happend once more.. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: What do you get when you upload your files? Show us your configuration and which are the size of files that you are trying to upload

Comment: This is what i am getting when i try to upload my database " No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. ". The size of my database is 2.2Mb. And i used your values.

Comment: Are you using windows? maybe a permissions error? [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149757/phpmyadmin-no-data-received-to-import-error-how-to-fix)

Comment: No i am using xubuntu 14.04 lts. I have made the changes using sudo.

Comment: Are you sure that permissions are ok to read and write files?¿

Comment: I am pretty sure about the permissions issue because i have done the same changes in the past, and worked pretty well.

Comment: it does not seems a size problem. Could you try to upload a light file with create databse sentence for example

Comment: I downloaded a databa from phpMyadmin and uploaded it again with no problem

Comment: I erased the logs and refreshed the page , but i did not see something.