# Uploading (small) file with phpMyAdmin not possible

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm using `MySQL 5.7.33` with `phpMyAdmin 5.1.0` on `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)`.

For some reason, I have no idea what has changed in the meanwhile, I'm not able to upload files via the Import feature in phpMyAdmin.

I exported a small table via the phpMyAdmin Export feature. The file has 20 KB. After deleting the table from the database, I use the Import feature in phpMyAdmin to upload the file.

I get the following error message:

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
> the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
> configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

I checked `FAQ 1.16.`. My php.ini is located at `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` and has the following values:

- max_execution_time = 60
- upload_max_filesize = 64
- memory_limit = 128M
- post_max_size = 70M

The file name is `.sql` but it's the same with `.zip`.

Why does uploading/importing not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29889688/10720730 Have a look at this link may be it will solve your problem

Comment: @Danish I changed `php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp` to `php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /tmp` because `/tmp` has 777 rights, but it's still the same.

Comment: Is that `upload_max_filesize` correct? If so, you have limited uploads to just 64 bytes! Perhaps you meant it to be 64M.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks, that did the trick: I added a trailing`M` like this: `upload_max_filesize = 64M` and now it's working.